# is there a way to grant read-only access to IIS config?

Tags: security, iis

Is there a way to provide limited access to IIS config, either via a tool shipped with IIS or another utility? In our case we need to give some users a read-only type of access, to be able to see IIS configuration but not modify it.
It is Windows Server 2003, IIS 6.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read-only access to the configuration is not possible within IIS. At least it isn't with built-in functionality.

IIS was designed to only allow read/write access to Administrators.

Non-administrative users have do not have the permission to neither write nor read the configuration as configuration access would already provide a potential security breach / disclosure.

Still there is the chance that one of the various configuration-frontends or control panels for IIS support this functionality.

Comment: I found a reference to this becoming possible in IIS 7: http://www.webservertalk.com/message1370833.html
Do you know if that is true?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the most easily-readable form, but the on-disk IIS metabase is just an XML file from IIS 6 on. Any information you need can come from there.

Comment: Thank you, is there a UI tool to allow viewing that info in a friendly format?